How can I express two positive integers as the real and imaginary part of an exponential sum
In the following problem, suppose you have two positive integers $A$, $B$, $A$ odd, $B$ even and let $A^2+B^2=p$ a prime.
Let $g$ be a primitive root modulo $n$. For any $b$ in $\mathbb{Z}^{\times}_n=\{g, g^2,…,g^{\varphi(n)-1},g^{\varphi(n)}\}$ there is a unique $k=I_g(b) \in [1, \varphi(n)]$ such that
\begin{equation}
g^k \equiv b \pmod n
\end{equation}
$k$ is called the index or discrete logarithm of $b$ (with base $g$) modulo the integer $n$.
Define the following sum
\begin{equation}
S=\sum_{x=0}^{\frac{p-1}{2}} \exp\{\frac{1}{2} \pi i I_g(x^4+a^4)\}
\end{equation}
where $a$ is any nonzero fixed quadratic residue $\pmod p$.
I would like to prove that, if $p \equiv 1 \pmod 8$, then
\begin{equation}
S=-A-iB
\end{equation}
For example, i would like to rewrite $S$ in a way that exclude the zero terms in the index.
Many thanks for any help.

Is $n=p$ the rest of the way?

What is $a$ in the definition of $S?$ If it is $A,$ don't mix case like that - write $A.$

$A$ is an odd integer, $a$ is a fixed quadratic residue $\pmod p$, $p$ prime, and $n$ is an integer such that $\mathbb{Z}_n^{\times}$ has primitive roots.

I only used the integer $n$ to define the index. The problem is about the modulus $p$ prime.
